# RNCryptor Encrypt in iOS and Decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, ios, encryption, aes, rncryptor

I've been trying to use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor) to encrypt a string in iOS and have the app post the encrypted string to a server which will decrypt the string in PHP.

Everything appears to be working fine (no error messages) until the end when the PHP script returns an empty string.

I think the problem is in the iOS code because when I tried to decrypt the string in the example [decrypt.php](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-php/blob/master/examples/decrypt.php), it worked fine.

iOS:

```
NSString *key = @"myPassword";
NSString *string = @"Secret String";
NSData *plain = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *cipherData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:plain withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:key error:&error];
NSString *cipherString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[cipherData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then I post the cipherString to the following PHP script

PHP:

```
require 'autoload.php';
$password = "myPassword";
$base64Encrypted = $_POST['data'];
$cryptor = new \RNCryptor\Decryptor();
$plaintext = $cryptor->decrypt($base64Encrypted, $password);
echo $plaintext;
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: I learned from [this discussion](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/issues/142) that when I entered the Base64 from the `cipherString` directly to the PHP, without the POST, it worked perfectly. Any thoughts?

Comment: PHP has non-standard padding, it is not PKCS#7.

Comment: Breakup the last statement into it's two components so you can find out if the is the encryption or Base5 encoding that is failing.

Comment: @Zaph RNCryptor != mcrypt, so the PKCS#7 comment probably does not apply. Note that there are multiple versions of RNCrypt, make sure that the versions match!

Comment: What I found is that if I enter in the data from the `cipherString` into the PHP script (without using POST) it works fine, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$cryptor = new \RNCryptor\Decryptor();
```

by

```
$cryptor = new \RNCryptor\RNCryptor\Decryptor;
```